# How can I select all items referenced by a specific list:reference field?

Tags: python, database, web2py

My simplified database is

```
db.define_table('my_items',Field('name_'),
            format = '%(name_)s'
)

db.define_table('my_categories',Field('name_'),
            Field('slug'),
            Field('items_', 'list:reference my_items'),
            format = '%(name_)s'
            )
```

in controllers I try to get every item in specific category:

```
def test():
    items = db(db.my_items.id.belongs(db(db.my_categories.slug == request.args[0])._select(db.my_categories.items_)[0])).select(db.my_items.ALL)
    return dict(items=items)
```

this returns nothing even when there is categories in the database with some items assigned, and with a correct slug given. Am I using `belongs` incorrectly? Do not suggest me to use a third table, this is intentionally denormalized.

Comment: The query returns rows object, as I would expect, but when I try to iterate through it, it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, don't do a nested select. Instead, do a separate query to get the list of id's:

```
item_ids = db.my_categories(slug=request.args[0]).items_
items = db(db.my_items.id.belongs(item_ids)).select()
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why nested select does not. Wasn't it intended for exactly this purpose?

Comment: No, the nested select works when the select returns a set of records, with each record contributing exactly one value to be included in the belongs list. It does not work when selecting a single record that stores an entire list in a single field.